# How to create a measure that is a virtual table of the rows that are not contained in one table and contained in another

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I need to create a measure with a logical DAX function that will iterate row by row between three tables and it will return me a virtual table of the rows that are in the first table and not in the other two.

My goal is to create a Maintenance Dashboard and I need to show how many activities were canceled.

The data is organized by the following:

Table 1 is dAcitivities0, this table is the first planning that happened in the begninning of the year.

Table 2 is the fReporgrammed, it shows me all the reprogrammed activities (dates) and it has the ID from dActivities0;

Table 3 is the fExecuted, it shows me all the activities that were executed and it is also filtered by dAcitivities with its ID.

[image: dAcitivities0]

[image: fExecuted]

[image: fReprogrammed]

[image: Relationship fExecuted]

[image: Relationship fReporgrammed]

Comment: This can be done using [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/except-function-dax) function, but unless you give more information about your model (and sample data and expected results) it is highly unlikely to get any specific answer.

Comment: Hey Andrey!
I updated the post! See if it helps, please!

Comment: Screenshots aren't quite usable, because it isn't possible to use the data without manually re-enter it. And you missed the expected output.